# Is “Go against type” a stand-alone popular idiom?

Tags: phrases, idioms

Today’s New York Times carries an article with the headline, “[James Gorman of Morgan Stanley, **Going Against Type**](http://www.nytimes.com/2014/06/29/business/james-gorman-of-morgan-stanley-going-against-type.html?ref=business&_r=0),” followed by the lead copy:

> Forgoing Wall Street flash, Morgan Stanley’s chief executive is finding safer ways for the firm to make money.

I first guessed “Go against type” as “go against typical pattern or traditional way of thinking, which usually means ‘aggressive, abrasive and revolutionary,” but the succeeding copy goes against my preconception:

“In the process, James Gorman and Morgan Stanley are becoming the face of what may be Wall Street’s future: highly profitable, to be sure, but with fewer of the grand ambitions or larger-than-life personalities that have always characterized the place. “I’m pretty invisible, and that’s just fine,” he acknowledged."

It seems “go against type” implies James Gorman is taking a steadier and life-sized approach of management as against aggressive and speculative business approaches of Morgan Stanley in the past.

However, I don’t find the phrase, “Go against type” neither in CED or OED, though I find “Go against sb./ sth (flow, the grain)” in CED.

Is “Go against type” a stand-alone idiom, or just one of variations of “Go against sth,”?

Can “go against type” be often used in such a way of simply meaning “different from the old way,” as used in the above article, without projecting any revolutionary, ambitious, and abrasive tones and a sort of bulldozing approach that come first from the word, “go against X”?

Comment: In the media industry it certainly is, but as a general phrase this is unlikely to be heard much, if ever. There is actually a wiki page about this: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PlayingAgainstType

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think *go against type* is derived  from the more common expression [playing against type](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PlayingAgainstType):

hinting at the fact that James Gorman is not 'acting as usual' but he is changing his attitude towards employees  at Morgan Stanley. By letting his top bond trader go refusing to pay huge bonuses he let all others trades understand that things have changed and probably a more stable and less speculative approach is expected from them.

> The hiring of an actor to play a certain part which differs fundamentally from roles the actor is famous for or has played in the past. For instance, an actress who is known for playing kindly old grandma types suddenly cast as a scheming murderess. This is generally done when an actor wants to 'stretch his/her wings' or 'try something different'. It usually leads to an Oscar for the actor in question. Often, it can be very useful in The Reveal. Comedies will frequently use this trope for laughs; a wacky line will often sound much funnier coming out of the mouth of someone you'd never expect to say such a thing. If it works very well, it can even change their career.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=go%20against%20type%2C%20playing%20against%20type&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgo%20against%20type%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cplaying%20against%20type%3B%2Cc0) 
shows a recent increase in the use of the expression *go against type* though it is not still that common.

I think it is an effective expression used to convey the idea that there is a change in attitude from a somewhat fixed or usual one.

Comment: From your answer and Ngram chart, it seems to be a pretty new phrase, and not the derivative from the idiom, "go against sth." Doesn't it?

Comment: Looking at the Ngram it seems _play against type_ was likely derived from _cast against type_. Through a bit of googling I found some usage of _date against type_, and _write against type_ and some others. Possibly _against type_ is becoming a phrase unto itself.

Comment: @Yoichi-san ~ mine is just an assumption, since 'playing against type' is easily found in general reference while 'go against type', as you said, is not. Plus the way it is used in the article suggests that the meaning is very close to it. As Neil suggests in his comment 'against type' is probably the 'core' sentence which is more often used with verbs like cast and play. –

Comment: @Josh61.Your quote from tvtropes.org’s definition of “play the type” really matches the role that James Gorman has performed. He took an entirely different approach from his predecessors in running new Morgan Stanley. Clearly “Go against type” isn’t a kin of “Go against flow / the grain” that I first associated with.

Comment: Even more common, and still closely related to the thespian context, is [*{act} out of character*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/out+of+character). @Yoichi - I assume you've got the main point now, that if someone *plays/goes against type*, the "type" they're not following is *their own established nature*, not some more general concept relating to society at large.

Comment: @FunbleFinger. Well, that’s very important point. I missed that point first. I thought ‘type’ means the pattern their predecessors had pursued for. Now it is their ‘own’ type. But I’m not sure of whether it is the ‘type’ James Gorman had played before his assuming CEO, or the Morgan Stanlay management including Gorman himself had played in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Your instinct is basically correct, in that “Go against type” as “go against typical pattern or traditional way of thinking."

In the Wall Street context, it does NOT mean "aggressive, abrasive and revolutionary” because those are terms that could define Wall St. firms, i.e. Morgan Stanley's peers.

Having "fewer of the grand ambitions or larger-than-life personalities" is actually "going against type" when it is true that such "have always characterized the place."